# Why did the shopkeeper get mad at me?

Tags: nethack

So I was about to lead my Wizard to Dlvl2, when suddenly

```
A trap door opens up under you!
"Hello, bp!  Welcome to Angmagssalik's general store!"
```

I land right into a shop on level 2. I try to leave the store, but step on an unpaid item with autopickup on.

```
"For you, most gracious lady; only 1 for this gray stone."
v - a gray stone (unpaid, 1 zorkmid).
```

No biggie. (I had  29$ anyway.)

```
What do you want to drop? [$a-ruv or ?*] 
You drop a gray stone (unpaid, 1 zorkmid).
What do you want to drop? [$a-ru or ?*] 
Never mind.
```

I move to leave the shop. The turn I move next to him,

```
Angmagssalik hits!  Angmagssalik hits! --more--
You die...  Angmagssalik gratefully inherits all your possessions.
Do you want your possessions identified? [ynq] (y) 

                                                          ┌───────────┐
                                                          │·+%?)m(%[%(│
                                                          │·?=?)[??[*!│
                                                          ▒@%/([*?%?!]│
                                                          │@%%%!?!/+%(│
                                                    :     │·m!****![=%│
                                                          │·*%/?%!)/%]│
                                                          └───────────┘

Bp the Evoker             St:12 Dx:15 Co:11 In:17 Wi:12 Ch:9  Neutral
Dlvl:2  $:29 HP:0(15) Pw:19(19) AC:8  Xp:2/20 T:383
```

...uh. What did I do exactly to anger the shopkeeper?

Comment: You auto-pickup stones? For your future utility, that's a recipe for disaster; some gray stones can very much end your life. This isn't one of them, however.

Comment: @Grace Yeah, I really need to set up a decent autopickup pattern.

Comment: Most auto-pickups aren't bad; the only two you have to watch out for are Scrolls and Stones. I'm sure "What items do I have to be careful about picking up from the ground" or "What makes a safe auto-pickup" or some much nicer title, would make a very nice question.

Comment: @Grace corpses too :)

Comment: That is true, with 2 cases instead of just one!

Comment: Auto-pickup armor + bones pile = overloaded from armor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Do you want your possessions identified? [ynq] (y) y
<snip/>
e - a ring of conflict (worn)
```

...*duh*. >.<

Comment: I was about to write this answer! Wargh. Well, it's good enough you found the answer. A ring of conflict (you meant ring, right? As a wizard, you start with rings) will cause things to fight anything; this is probably why those mimics aren't mimicking items anymore. But aside from that, there's nothing else which would've caused that shopkeeper to hit you.

Comment: Note that if you had done anything to anger the shopkeeper, you would have gotten a message about him getting angry before he attacked you.

Comment: @sepp yeah, hence the confusion. :/